# Type contraint error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've come across an issue where the TypeScript compiler is complaining about type constraint errors, but everything looks correct to me so I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's a simplified example:

```
// Base module
module Base {
   export interface Scope<TConfiguration> {
      configuration: TConfiguration;
   }

   export class Controller<TScope extends Scope<TConfiguration>, TConfiguration> {
      $scope: TScope;
   }    
}

// Implementation module
module Impl {
   export interface Configuration {
   }

   export interface Scope extends Base.Scope<Configuration> {
   }

   export class Controller extends Base.Controller<Scope, Configuration> {
   }
}
```

If you paste the code into the editor at http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/ you should see the error I'm getting:

```
Type 'Impl.Scope' does not satisfy the constraint 'Base.Scope<TConfiguration>' for type parameter 'TScope extends Base.Scope<TConfiguration>'.
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine; this was a bug in the compiler. In the upcoming 0.9.5 release this code compiles without error.

Comment: Thanks! Has a release date been scheduled for 0.9.5?

Comment: The beta is now available. https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TypeScript%200.9.5%20beta

Answer (score 0):

The compiler seems unhappy about using the TConfiguration type parameter within the constraint of the TScope type parameter.

Here is an example that compiles - without using the second type parameter within the constraint.

```
// Base module
module Base {
   export interface Scope<TConfiguration> {
      configuration: TConfiguration;
   }

   export class Controller<TScope extends Scope<Impl.Configuration>, TConfiguration> {
      $scope: TScope;
   }    
}

// Implementation module
module Impl {
   export interface Configuration {
   }

   export interface Scope extends Base.Scope<Configuration> {
   }

   export class Controller extends Base.Controller<Scope, Configuration> {
   }
}
```

Possible solutions...

Your `Scope` is an interface, so perhaps you don't really need to specify the exact "type of scope" - as long as it is a `Scope`... Your constraint would only allow you to call properties and functions on `Scope` anyhow...

```
// Base module
module Base {
   export interface Scope<TConfiguration> {
      configuration: TConfiguration;
   }

   export class Controller<TConfiguration> {
      $scope: Scope<TConfiguration>;
   }    
}
```

It *is* possible in TypeScript for a generic function to use the type argument passed to the enclosing generic class... this means you could do something like this:

```
// Base module
module Base {
   export interface Scope<TConfiguration> {
      configuration: TConfiguration;
   }

   export class Controller<TConfiguration> {
      $scope: Scope<TConfiguration>;

      addScope<TScope extends Scope<TConfiguration>>(scope: TScope) {
          this.$scope = scope;
      }
   }    
}

// Implementation module
module Impl {
   export interface Configuration {
   }

   export interface Scope extends Base.Scope<Configuration> {
   }

   export class Controller extends Base.Controller<Configuration> {
   }
}
```